# Reading files FB2 with help FileReader and deduce on the HTML page

Tags: javascript, html

I'm making a web reader on JS and come across with a problem. As i understand, with help FileReader I can read only text, arraybuffer and URL. Native JS is working with txt format without any problem. Received and deduced. I tryed search answer on question on the google, how to work with FB2 format, but not find no one deployed answer and answers about this topic not many as i hoped. Also, i did not see libraries, which could help me read this format and work with him. I be very pleasure if anyone could help me with my problem and will show me examples how work with FB2 format.

Comment: Fb2 это довольно простой xml.

Comment: Sorry, this part of SO is for questions in Russian. Please, use stackoverflow.com for questions in English or translate your question.

Comment: есть целая вики от разработчика формата http://www.fictionbook.org/index.php/FictionBook